# How to refactor an application with multiple switch cases?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an application which takes an integer as input and based on the input calls static methods of different classes. Every time a new number is added, we need to add another case and call a different static method of a different class. There are now 50 cases in the switch and every time I need to add another case, I shudder. Is there a better way to do this.

I did some thinking and came up with this idea. I use the strategy pattern. Instead of having a switch case, I have a map of strategy objects with the key being the input integer. Once the method is invoked, it will look up the object and call the generic method for the object. This way I can avoid using the switch case construct.

What do you think?

Comment: What kind of case values are they? Can you show us an example (or three)?

Comment: Sounds good. But you might still be just scratching the surface, as having 50 different classes where you call **static**  sounds like the real issue here. static is an abnormality in good OO design. In other words : you should step back and look into that part of your design. Those switch statements are a symptom of your problem, the root cause lies deeper!

Comment: I think your map of strategy objects idea is a good way to go.

Comment: When it's possible to change the integer to an enumeration you can go with that as well. It might be better in this case because integers are not really a good reference to choose a implementation of something. In a year or two no one knows which integer is for what and that's a messy situation.

Comment: @JanSchumacher Actually the integer is not a random thing. Each case calls an operation, which is defined in an xsd. Castor is used to generate the java classes and it also generates these integers to map an operation name. So enums are not an option.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree and that is why I want to change these classes to strategy classes implementing a common interface and change the method from static to non static

Comment: "call a different static method of a different class" - is there a wide commonality between those methods ? Can you make it an object created using the integer key ?

Comment: If the numbers are 1 (or 0) through 50, you may even use an array of strategy objects instead of a map. The map is of course more extensible in case someone invents the need for accepting number -1 or 1000001.

Comment: Than you could do the strategy interface thing. If you know the integers you can provide them as keys in a map and access the needed strategy directly with a get. I think this might be the cleanest way.